# Problem on style a button

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Hello i am new on  Silverlight, i tring to make a base for a button and that button will change the central image accoring to the situation, however some parts will continue the same, for this reason i make a UserControl and i call that user Control from the code and add to the grid that i need.
But this Usercontrol that i am trying to add have a style pre-defined and i don´t geted how i change de image background.
Here are the code that i am using;

```
ModelsBase teste = new ModelsBase();
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Images/person.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;img.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(img_ImageOpened);
img.Height = img.Width = 128;
teste.Conteudo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
this.ContentModels.Children.Add(teste);
```

The envent img_ImageOpened is called so the image is loaded, but not is displayed.

Sorry for bad english

If someone find out where is the problem, please aswer

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your image to the tree, it needs to be a content of some panel or content control. Also consider using XAML and MVVM for user interface creation ... and Google translate for questions :)

Hope this helps. Cheers!